# Cannot be resloved to variable error while merging hours of employees

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to accept an Employee object and merge the hours of said employee. 
For example if e1 had hours: [8,8,8,2,0,0,0] and e2 had hours: [0,0,0,4,10,0,0]. Then, when e1.mergeEmployee(e2) is excecuted, the e1 will have hours: [8,8,8,6,10,0,0].

However, I cannot get to that step of the code, because I am getting a resolved to variable error in my code:

```
public class Employee {

private double[] hours;
private String name;
private double payRate;

public Employee() {
    hours = new double[7];
}

public Employee(String name, double payRate) {
    hours = new double[7];
    this.name = name;
    this.payRate = payRate;

}

public double getHours(int day) {
    return hours[day];

}

public void setHours(int day, double num) {
    hours[day] = num;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getPayRate() {
    return payRate;
}

public int getNumDaysWorked() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        if(hours[i] > 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public double getTotalHours() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        count += hours[i];
    }
    return count;
}

public double getWeekdayHours() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        count += hours[i];
    }
    return count;
}

public double getWeekendHours() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 5; i <7; i++) {
        count += hours[i];
    }
    return count;
}

public void newWeek() {
    for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        hours[i] = 0;
    }
    //Arrays.fill(array,0.0); ??? 
}

public double getPay() {
    double totalPay = 0.0;
    double timeHalf = (payRate * 1.5);
    double timeDouble = (payRate * 2.0);
    double bonus = 50.00;

    if(getNumDaysWorked() == 7) {
        totalPay += bonus;
    }

    if(getWeekendHours() > 0) {
        totalPay += (getWeekendHours() * timeDouble);
    }

    if(getWeekdayHours() > 40) {
        totalPay += (payRate * 40) + ((getWeekdayHours() - 40)*timeHalf);
    }
    else {
        totalPay += (getWeekdayHours() * payRate);
    }

    return totalPay;
}

public void mergeEmployee(Employee emp) {
    if(this.getHours(day).equals(emp.getHours(day))) {    

    }
}
}
```

the error is in the if statement of the mergeEmployee class. 
I am pretty brain dead, so I apologize if I am missing something easy and big.

Comment: It will be easy for us if you tell *I am getting a resolved to variable error* **where ?**

Comment: In your mergeEmployee method, what is that variable 'day'?

Comment: its below my code, sorry should have put it up top. The error is in the mergeEmployee method at the very bottom of the code

Comment: Its a trial and error. If I take the variable day out, it gives this error: The method getHours(int) in the type Employee is not applicable for the 
  arguments ()

Comment: And what if you change the '.equals()' to just '=='?

Comment: It is giving me the same error. That the type Employee is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: with your variable day.

Comment: Yes I still get an error, however, it is the resolved to variable error

Comment: Can you edit your code so that the variable 'day' is declared somewhere?

Comment: If I write it in this way ... public void mergeEmployee(Employee emp,int day) {
  if(this.getHours(day) == (emp.getHours(day))) {

Comment: If I write it like so^ all the syntax errors disappear. However, my code is not 100% done yet, so I cannot test to see if that it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a declared variable 'day' in that function's scope. I think what you're trying to do is use this in a for-loop, like this:

```
for(int day=0; day<7; day++) {
    if(this.getHours(day) == emp.getHours(day)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Also, in your example it seems like you're just adding the nth element of the two arrays together, so why not just do:

```
for(int day=0; day<7; day++) {
    this.setHours(day, this.getHours(day) + emp.getHours(day)); 
}
```

Comment: thank you, both of these look very promising and I will test them in the morning. Ill throw the check on this if either of them work